# Error rich:panelMenu example showcase doesn't render

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces, jboss7.x

Hi i can't replicate the example in the richfaces 4.3.0.Final showcase:
     http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu&skin=blueSky
Specifically in the rich:panelMenu component, when i run the code the panelMenu doesn't responde,and the panelMenuItem doesn't show, I change the code like this:

```
<rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax">
```

to

```
<rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" mode="ajax">
```

and the panelMenuItems show and working, but this part doesn't work:

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
      <rich:panel rendered="#{not empty panelMenuBean.current}">
                <h:outputText value="#{panelMenuBean.current} selected" id="current" />
      </rich:panel>
 </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Why? tnks.

Comment: You know, "doesn't work" is not a clear description of a problem... Also, what do you mean by "the panelMenu doesn't responde"? The screen doesn't change? Does an HTTP request is made, at least? (Use Firebug or the developer tools to check that). Try to provide the full context in which your code is running, and the relevant code in your PanelMenuBean.

Comment: the panelMenu doesn't expand, and the rich:panelMenuItem components(label="")not render in the page.

Comment: Is a spring, jsf,richfaces 4.3.0 Final project, I work with xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested with the exact same code from the showcase (I simply copied the whole `h:form`), and it worked alright.

You just have to create a backing bean called `PanelMenuBean` with the `current` String property and the `updateCurrent` listener method (receiving an ItemChangeEvent for the `itemChangeListener` attribute, according to the [VDL docs for panelMenu](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/panelMenu.html)):

```
@ManagedBean
public class PanelMenuBean {

    private String current;

    public void updateCurrent(ItemChangeEvent evt) {
        current = evt.getNewItemName();
    }

    // getter and setter ...
}
```

Comment: same, the panelmenu not expand, it's a spring application, maybe is the path where i put the managebean? (src/main/java/ --com.xxx.xxx.common)

Comment: As is happens, I also tested it in a Spring application, but that shouldn't matter, cause the code does not use Spring features. And the path where you put the managed bean also shouldn't matter. Are you trying it in a brand-new project? Cause if not, I'd recommend it, you are probably missing something else not related to RichFaces.

Comment: I try a brand-new project created in eclipse and it works, but my application use myfaces 2.1.10 for JSF

Comment: Well, make the brand-new project to use the same JARs that the other application is using, just so that you can properly compare them. If you test it with Mojarra and then with MyFaces, and it works with one and not with the other, it would be easier to find out what the problem is. But if it works with both, then the problem is probably something else in your application.