# Richfaces 3.3.4Final: looking for a managed bean example for panelMenu

Tags: richfaces, javabeans, managed

I have read example of rich:panelMenu (http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/panelMenu.jsf?c=panelMenu) for richfaces 3.3.4.Final however I wanted to see how *updateCurrent* method was implemented in a managed bean, but I was not successful to find an example.

However, I ran into this thread, ([Error rich:panelMenu example showcase doesn't render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075683/error-richpanelmenu-example-showcase-doesnt-render)) and I was able to get an idea of how that method is implemented for richfaces 4.3.0, but I believe that **ItemChangeEvent** class is introduced for richfaces 4.x version not on 3.x.

Can someone share with me what parameter of richfaces class I should expect in updateCurrent method for version 3.3.4.Final?